# Adding a new secondary in MongoDB to Distribute Load

Tags: mongodb, load, sharding, mongodb-java

I have two shards on three machines (using mongodb 1.8.2):

```
nodeI   including:   shard1(primary) and shard2(primary)
nodeII  including:   shard1(secondary) and shard2(secondary)
nodeIII including:   shard1(arbiter) and shard2 (arbiter)
```

NodeII load is getting very high(CPU and IO), and NodeI is high as well, but a little better than nodeII.

In my java client I designated code to only query NodeII, while NodeI is just used for writing.

I am planning to convert nodeIII from arbiter to secondary to share the read load on NodeII.

Do you think this is a good idea and if I do this, what should I consider, or do you have other suggestions to lower the load?

Comment: Would be helpful if you can post some more details: hardware specs for your three servers, as well as a [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) link with some [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongostat/) output from `Node I` and `Node II`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the arbiter hardware has similar specifications to your secondary, the approach you are suggesting seems reasonable as it will distribute the secondary reads. Usually arbiters have very low hardware specs or are on shared hardware, but I am assuming that this is not the case in your configuration.

If you have an odd number of servers in the replica set you will no longer need an arbiter.

You may want to [look into Read Preference here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/replication/#read-preference), in particular you might be interested in specifying tag sets to select a secondary.

Comment: ,I'm using java client to connect mongoS,I'm afraid if the client could automatically balance the read requests to the two secondarys,do I need some specail config.and I'm sorry what's this mean:"in particular you might be interested in specifying tag sets to select a secondary."

Comment: The read requests will automatically be balanced between the two secondaries. If you like, you can specify special rules on when you want to read which secondary using tag sets, but this is not necessary. I only mentioned it so you could look into the link I gave it if you were interested.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a secondary does not necessarily "distribute" the load as you might expect.  Without getting to the root of your performance problems, you may just be setting up for more challenges.

In particular, adding a secondary to your existing servers will:

- increase the I/O load on the server where you add the secondary (you are now replicating & writing a full extra copy of the data)
- provide more contention for reading from the server the secondary is syncing from
- potentially cause that secondary to lag behind the primary during heavy read activity (which may be of concern if you are expecting strong consistency).

You should also consider what happens in the case of failure.  If your servers are struggling under the current load, things will probably dramatically melt down if any one of your physical servers has problems and all the traffic ends up hitting a single server.

Ideally you should run [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongostat/) or similar [monitoring tools](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Monitoring+and+Diagnostics) to get a better understanding of the performance characteristics of your servers and what might be contributing to the load (memory pressure, lock %, I/O, network, ..).  It would be helpful if you could post a sampling of mongostat output to [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) or similar.

You should also review your common queries with [explain()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) to understand index usage, and check if they require access to all shards or are being directed to a specific one.

If all 3 servers are the same hardware spec, as a short term improvement I would consider:

- Removing the arbiters and replace them with secondary nodes. This will provide extra data redundancy in the event one of your servers fails and help prevent all of the load from landing on one server.
- Stepping down the primary on NodeI, so that NodeI and NodeII each have a primary and secondary (rather than the two primaries on NodeI and two secondaries on NodeII).  The primary and secondary servers have different write characteristics so this may balance the load better.
- Checking your shard key(s) and common queries to confirm they will reasonably balance reads and writes.  Potential problems including a "hot spot" where all writes to a collection hit a single shard .. or queries which hit all shards to get a result.
- Testing the change in performance if you *don't* read from the secondaries.  It may seem counter-intuitive, but reading from secondaries may actually be causing you other issues depending on the nature of your queries.

Lastly, you mention using 1.8.2.  There are significant performance and locking/yielding improvements in MongoDB 2.0 and 2.2, as well as other bug fixes.  It would be worth testing an upgrade in your development environment as this may address some of your issues.

Comment: Thank you very very much Stennie!Your answer very detailed and very helpful!I will try the short term method,and a few days latter I will try the root solution:add new sharding replicat Sets.
By the way I have a silly question,I don't understand "Writes to a secondary will often result in higher I/O than primary writes"?
you mean the secondary's IO pressure heavier than primary?
I understanded the primary oplog reduces many updates to one update and then send the one update to secondary?so why the seconday more heavy IO pressure?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry another silly question:how to check "lock status" when I use mongostat,is there Lock threshold,how is good how is bad.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jack: Sorry, that wasn't a reasonable generalization on the performance characteristics of primary and secondary; they can be different based on a number of factors including your read preferences and types of updates. With multi-updates, a single statement that is applied on the primary can be converted into several [operations in the oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#oplog) for relaying to the secondaries. As far as lock status in `mongostat`, you want to look at the `lock %`. There isn't really good or bad, it's more about the history.  Extended high lock % is bad :).

Comment: If possible, you should add your servers to the free [Mongo Monitoring Service (MMS)](https://mms.10gen.com/help/install.html).  MMS provides some helpful tracking of operational and performance characteristics.  Alternatively you could set up your own [monitoring](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Monitoring+and+Diagnostics) using something like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/).